# Add name attr to generated <span>

Tags: jquery, dom

I am using this line of code:

```
initWords($('<span></span>').addClass('word').text(data.word).appendTo('#wordBank'));
```

Along with creating a `<span class="word">word</span>` I want too add name="WORD HERE" to the  tag.

I see that `$(".word").attr("name")`, but is this how I set the attr name to the `span.word`?

Answer (score 9):

To set an attribute use [2 parameters](http://docs.jquery.com/Attributes/attr#keyvalue):

```
$(".word").attr("name", "somevalue");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$(".word").attr("name")
```

you finds the *name* attribute of the first *span* in the page.

If you want to set a value using the following syntax:

1) Use "attr(key, value)" to set a single property to a value, the matched element(s):

```
$("img").attr("key", "value");
```

2) Use "attr(properties)" to set some attributes for the matched element(s):

```
$("img").attr({ key1: "value1", key2: "value2" });
```